# web api - disable origins not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api

i wont to enable access to my web api for only one origin. 
I tried the next steps:

1.add this lines to WebApiConfig:

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("https://allow-access.com", "*", "*");
 config.EnableCors(cors);
```

2.add this attribute above the ApiController:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "https://allow-access.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

but still the api allow access to all origin.
Someone has an idea why?

Comment: Please give some details how this service gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, below statement will enable CORS only for one origin "`https://allow-access.com`"

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("https://allow-access.com", "*", "*");
 config.EnableCors(cors);
```

I'm not sure how you are testing your API for all origins but as per the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#set-the-allowed-origins), only this will enable all origins in Web API:

```
// Allow CORS for all origins. (Caution!)
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```